# Changing Element Classes with jQuery using conditionals and a timer

Tags: javascript, jquery

Essentially i have three different classes that can be applied to an element on my page. Each holds a different background image and i want to use JQuery to find out which class is currently there and the remove that class and replace it with another. and then set a timer on it to run the function every 5000ms
this is what my code looks like

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
    var toggleImage = function(){
        if($(".home").hasClass("home1")){
            $(".home").removeClass("home1").addClass("home2")       }
        elseif($(".home").hasClass("home2")){
            $(".home").removeClass("home2").addClass("home3")
        }
        elseif($(".home").hasClass("home3")){
            $(".home").removeClass("home3").addClass("home1")
        }

    }

    setInterval(toggleImage(), 5000);​

    });
```

The class of home will always be there and im just trying to add and remove the other classes on the element. Im coming from PHP so im thinking maybe my syntax could be off.

Comment: Just FYI, you should explain what problem you actually have with your code. In this case the error error was obvious, but that's not always the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass a *function* to `setInterval`. Currently you are *calling* `toggleImage` and  pass its return value, which is `undefined`.

Don't call the function:

```
setInterval(toggleImage, 5000);​
```

At least in Firefox you would have gotten a runtime error:

> Error: useless setInterval call (missing quotes around argument?)

---

> Im coming from PHP so im thinking maybe my syntax could be off.

You are right, `elseif` should be `else if`. This is a syntax error and you should have seen it in the console as well.

---

[Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) to find syntax and runtime errors on your own.

Comment: Changed the code to reflect the changes that you gave me however it still isn't switching the classes. any idea what im still doing wrong. Also thank you for your quick reply.

Comment: Have a look at the console. Any errors? Without info it's impossible for me to tell you what could be wrong.

Comment: I tried to create a jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/g7394/) and got the error: `SyntaxError: illegal character`. It looks like you have a strange invisible character after `setInterval(toggleImage, 5000);​` (see the fiddle). You should remove that.

Comment: Removing the semicolon after setinterval resolved it.

Comment: That's basically what I meant! You had a strange invisible character after the semicolon after `setInterval` by removing the end of the line you removed that character was well. You can now end the semicolon again. Look at my fiddle in my previous comment. You should see a red dot at end of the line with `setInterval`. That's your strange character.

Comment: Quick other question. How could i hook a jquery fade effect into the switch?

Answer (score 1):

You want to pass setInterval a function. Calling toggleImage() runs the function and ends up passing setInterval the result. The correct syntax should be:

```
setInterval(toggleImage, 5000);
```